# The term 'Get-SmbOpenFile' is not recognized when running script from C# code

Tags: c#, powershell, remote-access

I have a PowerShell script that closes opened shared files on remote server

```
$User = "user"
$PWord = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "pas" -AsPlainText -Force
$Credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $User, $PWord
$cim = New-CimSession -ComputerName epicorlive -Credential $Credential
Get-SmbOpenFile -CimSession $cim | Where-Object Path -like "*dll\Form.dll" | Close-SmbOpenFile -Force
```

Running this script from native PowerShell window works fine.

but when i try to run from C# code there is an error:

```
The term 'Get-SmbOpenFile' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again
```

```
            string scriptText = //"\r\n" +
                "$User = \"user\"\r\n" +
                "$PWord = ConvertTo-SecureString -String \"pas\" -AsPlainText -Force\r\n" +
                "$Credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $User, $PWord\r\n" +
                "$cim = New-CimSession -ComputerName epicorlive -Credential $Credential\r\n" +

                "Get-SmbOpenFile -CimSession $cim | Where-Object Path -like \"*dll\\" + file + "\" | Close-SmbOpenFile -Force";
            
            Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
            runspace.Open();

            Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
            pipeline.Commands.AddScript(scriptText);

            Collection<PSObject> results = pipeline.Invoke();

            runspace.Close();

            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (PSObject obj in results)
            {
                stringBuilder.AppendLine(obj.ToString());
            }
```

Why is this command not recognized running from C#?
How can i fix it?

If there is some other options to close opened shared files on remote computer from C# code, I will be glad to hear about them :)

Comment: Runspaces don't auto-load modules by default, so you need to explicitly import the `SmbShare` module before calling `Get-SmbOpenFile`

Comment: Possibly the SmbShare module is only found under the SysWOW64 folder and your C# app is configured for x86 or vice versa (System32 using x64)?  You could try changing the platform target of your app to confirm.